# How to transform each xml node with Saxon XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

How can I use `Saxon` xslt transformation library to convert an xml file that contains many nodes to a plain csv string? Means, I want Saxon to concatenate each `employee` entry as csv, and put them all together.

This is the saxon setup, but I don't know how I could not transform an input xml file with it:

```
    //false = does not required a feature from a licensed version of Saxon.
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);

    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    compiler.compile(new StreamSource("transformation.xslt"));

    Serializer serializer = processor.newSerializer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

    //TODO 
    //String result = serializer...serializeNodeToString();
```

I want to transform the following xml:

```
<employees stage="test">
   <employee>
      <details>
         <name>Joe</name>
         <age>34</age>
      </details>
      <address>
         <street>test</street>
         <nr>12</nr>
      </address>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <address>....</address>
      <details>
         <!-- note the changed order of elements! -->
         <age>24</age>
         <name>Sam</name>
      </details>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

The `result` string should contain the following (one big string with linebreak separated csv lines):

```
test,Joe,34,test,12\n
test,Sam,24,...\n
```

Xslt might be similar to:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Do you have two questions here, how to use Saxon 9 with Java to perform an XSLT transformation and how to write an XSLT stylesheet for your particular task? As for the XSLT task, does the second `address` element not contain any child elements but only the text "...."? What defines the order for the CSV?

Comment: Both <details> and <address> don't contain further child elements. The order should be set by the order of `<xsl:value-of select...>` attributes.

Comment: Is `<address>....</address>` an example of real data or just lazyness to show the structure of the element twice? And it is still not clear whether you need help writing the XSLT (you have now posted one) and writing Java code to execute the XSLT or both? As for writing Java code to execute XSLT, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/samples/s9api.html.

Comment: I was just lazy not copying the address details again. And preferably I need assistance in how to properly transform the xml to string (java code), when using an existing xslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT template can be modified as below. The elements can be selected according to the required sequence.

```
<xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::employees/@stage, details/name, details/age, address/street, address/nr" separator=", " />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

After replacing the `...` with some dummy values in the `<address>` element the following output is generated using the above template.

```
test, Joe, 34, test, 12
test, Sam, 24, test1, 123
```

For transforming the XML (using XSLT) in Java, I use the following code snippet most of the time. This method returns the transformed XML as a `String`. The required library is `saxon9he.jar`. You may have to upgrade the library version for using with XSLT 3.0

```
public static String transformXML(String xml, InputStream xslFile) {
    String outputXML = null;
    try {
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile));
        Source xmlStream = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
        transformer.transform(xmlStream, result);
        outputXML = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        writer.close();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
        tce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputXML;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, StringWriter should must be closed. It implements Closable, hence you can use try-with-resource here.